# Get back an already deployed meteor app

Tags: deployment, meteor, meteorite

I have this app I deployed a few months back on meteor servers, let's say it's accessible via : myapp.meteor.com

Now I want to reverse the procedure and get back the code I deployed. (like doing a pull from myapp.meteor.com to my local machine) Is such thing possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is actually "No", because when you deploy your app to meteor servers, meteor build tool bundles it into node.js app and then uploads.

So you can pull only bundled & minified version of your app and its actually for node.js instead of meteor.

Comment: And how would I pull that minified version?

Comment: Hmm.. you should ask MDG for server part of code, because the "visible" part of the app that you can simply download via browser is only client side code